# Inserting lots of results (more than 1024) of a query into a table dynamically in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that executes a dynamic query, so I have a string called `@template`, that along my code is substituted by some instructions so after some handling I have a very big query:

```
--Init the template and tell it to insert results to TEMPORAL table
SET @template = 'SELECT {LotsOfColumns},{EvenMoreColumns} INTO TEMPORAL FROM '+ @table_name;
--some handling substitute {LotsOfColumns} and {EvenMoreColumns} 
--...
--...
-- replace strings
SET   @template    = REPLACE(@template, '{LotsOfColumns}',   @templateLotsOfColumns);
SET   @template    = REPLACE(@template, '{EvenMoreColumns}', @templateEvenMoreColumns);

--very big query!!

EXEC (@template);
```

As the *TEMPORAL* table is a runtime generated, I get a error of 1024 limit column

Msg 4505, Level 16, State 1, Procedure proc, Line 3
 exceeds the maximum of 1024 columns.

- Is there a way to indicate the table has more than 1024 columns?

Other option I was thinking is:

As I am doing a select statement I am receiving lots of results and insert them into a column, is there a way to change the above query so I am not doing this:

```
col1  col2  col3 ...  col1024   ... col3000
-------------------------------------------
14      34   45  ...      534   ...     657

but this??:

id   resultFromquery
--------------
1          1
2         34
3         45
...
1024     534
...
3000     657
```

I guess this is a better solution... But I do not know how to modify my query:

```
SET @template = 'SELECT {LotsOfColumns},{EvenMoreColumns} INTO TEMPORAL FROM '+ @table_name;

--some handling sustitute {LotsOfColumns} and {EvenMoreColumns} 
EXEC @template;
```

to do that

Comment: Are you receiving just one record (row) after execute your query? ie @table_name have just one record as shown in your second option??

Comment: I execute a very big query, and the results are inserted in a temporal table as a only one row with lots of columns, what I would like to do is get lots of rows and only 2 columns intead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build dynamically the UNPIVOT syntax as follows in order to get the desidered structure.

```
set @q='
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(col,2,10) AS INT) id, val resultFromquery
FROM '+ @table_name +'
UNPIVOT (val for col in ('+@templateLotsOfColumns+','+@templateEvenMoreColumns+')) unpvt'

exec(@q)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
    create table #temp(id int, [value] int)
    truncate table #temp
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    set @sql=''
    declare @counter int
    set @counter = 1
    while(@counter<3001)
    begin
      set @sql = 'insert into #temp(id, [value])
      select @counter, col'+CAST(@counter, varchar(4)) +' from '+@table_name
      sp_executesql @sql
      set @sql=''
    end
```

But i think your design is seriously flawed if you need to do this kind of thing.

Comment: The problem is that SQL Server does not allow me to have a table with more than 1024 columns, thats why I thought in that other option..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNPIVOT`. I just tested this on a 1025 column result set and that worked OK!

```
WITH T(col1,col2,col3,col1024,col3000)
AS (
SELECT  14,34,45,534,657 
)
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(col,4,10) AS INT) id, val AS resultFromquery
FROM T
UNPIVOT (val for col in (col1,col2,col3,col1024,col3000)) unpvt
```

Returns

```
id          resultFromquery
----------- ---------------
1           14
2           34
3           45
1024        534
3000        657
```